# How can I assemble this bar plot in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, data-analysis

I'm a begginer in Python Data Analysis and I'm having a hard time trying to figure this one out.

I want to create a bar plot where, *in X axis*, I get the Years spaced by 10 (1980 - 1990 - 2000...), and in the *Y axis*, the counted values stacked of all the "Genre" occurences respective to the year in the X axis.

Can anyone offer a hand here? Thanks in advance!

The dataset I'm working on follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might be an easier way to do this but no one has answered so I'll try and help:

I created a small mock DataFrame based on your's to work on:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

Genre = ['Misc','Action','Action','Action','Drama','Misc','Misc','Action']
Year = [1980,1980,1980,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990]
so = pd.DataFrame(Genre,Year).reset_index(drop=False)
so.columns = ['Year','Genre']

so.head()
```

```
    Year    Genre
0   1980    Misc
1   1980    Action
2   1980    Action
3   1990    Action
4   1990    Drama
5   1990    Misc
6   1990    Misc
7   1990    Action
```

What I want to get is a DataFrame telling me how many times each possible genre/year combination occurs.

```
sog = pd.DataFrame(so.groupby(['Year','Genre']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()).reset_index(drop=False)

sog.columns = ['year','genre','freq']

sog
```

```
    year    genre   freq
0   1980    Action  2
1   1980    Drama   0
2   1980    Misc    1
3   1990    Action  2
4   1990    Drama   1
5   1990    Misc    2
```

Great, now we just need arrays for each genre to pass into the plot.

```
bar_list = []
for g in sog.genre.unique():
    bar_list.append(np.array(sog[sog.genre == g].freq))

bar_list
```

```
[array([2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2], dtype=int64)]
```

Each array represents one genre and the number of times that genre appears in each year. For instance, the `[2,2]` array tells us that the 'Action' genre has two appearances in 1980 and two in 1990. We can use these arrays for a stacked bar plot:

```
genres = sog.genre.unique()

plt.bar([0,1],bar_list[0],label=genres[0])
plt.bar([0,1],bar_list[1],bottom=bar_list[0],label=genres[1])
plt.bar([0,1],bar_list[2],bottom=bar_list[0]+bar_list[1],label=genres[2])

plt.xticks([0,1], [1980,1990])
plt.ylim(0,8)
plt.legend()
```

Your number of `plt.bar()` calls will be equal to the number of unique genres (because each array in `bar_list` corresponds to one unique genre. Each time, you'll have to add the previous `bar_list[i]` entry to the `bottom` argument in `plt.bar()`, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: That's really clever! Thank you, Machetes